# Passing arguments to a function (observables) in Angular service?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have an angular project that displays the result of an SQL Query (MSSQL) in
a tabular form. I would like to add input fields in the HTML view to capture and send query parameters back to the Node.js to embedd them in the SQL statment ('where' clause). I have started with just one query parameter. Below is what I have got so far.

The code compiles with no error but I cant find a way to pass the query value (this.MedicineName) to the service and affect the changes in the output.

- Itemsearch.component.html

```
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Complete Search</h1>
    <label >Medicine Name:</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="MedicineName"  ><br><br> <-- Intend to take input here
    <div>{{MedicineName}}</div>
    <label >Company Name:</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="CompanyName" ><br><br>
    <label >Composition:</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Composition" ><br><br>
    <label >Purpose:</label>
    <input type="text"[(ngModel)]="Purpose"  ><br><br>
    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Product_Name</th>
            <th>Composition</th>
            <th>purpose</th>        
        </tr>
    
        <tr *ngFor="let com of lstitems">
            <th>{{com.Index}}</th>
            <th>{{com.Product_Name}}</th>
            <th>{{com.Composition}}</th>
            <th>{{com.Purpose}}</th>       
        </tr>
```

- iteamsearch.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
    import { Items } from 'src/app/classes/items';
    import { FreeapiService } from 'src/app/services/freeapi.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-itemsearch',
      templateUrl: './itemsearch.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./itemsearch.component.scss']
    })
    export class ItemsearchComponent implements OnInit {
    
      lstitems?: Items[]; 
      MedicineName: string = "";
      CompanyName: string = "";
      Composition: string = "";
      Purpose: string = "";
      
      constructor(public _freeApiService: FreeapiService) {}
    
      ngOnInit(): void {                 vvvvv <-- passing the input to service call here
      this._freeApiService.getItems(this.MedicineName).subscribe(data=> {this.lstitems = data;}); 
      }
    }
```

- freeapi.service.ts

```
    import {Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
    import { HttpClient, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class FreeapiService {  
      constructor(private http: HttpClient){ }
           
      getItems(val1: string): Observable<any> { 
        let params = new HttpParams();   
        params = params.set('var1', val1);
          
        return this.http.get("http://localhost:5000/first", {params: params})
      }
    }
```

In the service, I think the variable 'val1' should assume the value of "this.Medicine" and send it to the API. But, this is not happening.

Appreciate if I could get some pointers to fix this problem.

Comment: The `ngOnInit()` hook would be triggered as early as the component is initialized. You'd need some kind of submit mechanism (like a **Submit** button) and trigger the HTTP request from it's `(click)` event-handler.

Comment: @Michael, Thanks for the reply. I have tried the following. I am editing my post to show the modifications.

Comment: How do I mark @Michael D answer as accepted?